# element not found python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want the link of the button when they are clicked or those elements of button

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://fileml.com/l/0wC1#/offers")
elemlist=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("ul/li/a")
```

But elemlist is also empty
neither I can get those elements nor I can get the href
But once it clicked it opens some url

So is there any what that I can atleast get elements of those buttons

Comment: please include the source from which you're trying to scrape

Comment: o sorry for that i forgot

Comment: Please don't edit your question after it's answered... in this case, you edited the question to put the answer inside which makes the question not make any sense because it should have worked.

Comment: actually the answer was edited too .The answer that I got first was just adding // and to make sure that it was not that solution that resolved that error and // didnot worked well so i edited.Sorry for that if I violated StackOverflow policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get empty list because your `XPath` expression is incorrect.

Try below:

```
"//ul/li/a"
```

Note that `"//ul"` means *unordered list somewhere in the DOM* while just `"ul"` means *unordered list which is the root element*

Also make sure that you switched to `iframe` before searching for `ul`:

```
browser.switch_to.frame("offer-iframe")
```

Comment: Required list located inside an `<iframe id="offer-iframe">...</iframe>`. It contains its own DOM. You need to switch to that `iframe` to be able to access elements from iframes' DOM

Comment: I dont know about DOM.Can you just explain in brief a little

Comment: Simply put, DOM is HTML tree

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153050/discussion-between-nimish-bansal-and-andersson).